# How to move images in a gridLayout?

Tags: java, grid-layout

```
if(e.getSource() == UpButton) {
        kickBall("up");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == mvDBtn){
        kickBall("down");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == MvleftBtn){
        kickBall("right");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == MvLbutton) {
        kickBall("left");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == runBtn) {
           timer1();
    }
     }
    public void kickBall(String a) {

        if(a == "right") {

            //how to move

        }
        else if(a == "left") {
            //how to move

        }
        else if(a == "up") {
            //how to move

        }
        else if(a == "down") {
          //how to move
        }
```

I have a 13*16 grid layout and i want move a player(character).is it possible to move it pixel wise or should it moved a grid cell at a time.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. How is your game supposed to look? If you need pixel movements, the image should be drawn in the `paintComponent` method of a component like a `JPanel`. You have only shown a (partial) event handler, and we don't know what is supposed to happen.

Comment: It might pay to look into the official tutorial for custom painting, because it should cover what you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Comment: Whatever problems you’re having probably stem from using `==` to compare Strings.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java.